# get Google Doc from id just retrieved

Tags: javascript, java, jsf, google-drive-api, ajax4jsf

I am developing a Java - JSF web application in which I am showing a pop-up in order to let the user choose a document from Google Drive to download it.

To do that, I have some js code:

```
<script src="filepicker.js"></script>
<script>
    function initPicker() {
        var picker = new FilePicker({
            apiKey: 'MY_API_KEY',
            clientId:  my_client_id,
            buttonEl: document.getElementById('pick'),
            onSelect : function(file) {
                        if (file.id) {
                            sendLinkToBean(file.id);
                        } else {
                            alert('Unable to download file.');
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
</script>

<a4j:jsFunction name="sendLinkToBean" action="#{gPPersonFormBean.downloadFile()}">
    <a4j:param name="param1" assignTo="#{gPPersonFormBean.fileId}"/> 
</a4j:jsFunction>
```

The file.id arrives the Bean and I try to get it as shown in G.Drive's API:

```
public void downloadFile(){
    try {
        Drive driveService = getDriveService();
        OutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        driveService.files().get(fileId) .executeMediaAndDownloadTo(outputStream);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        String mess = "downloadFile(): " 
                + (e.getMessage()!=null?". "+e.getMessage():"")
                + (e.getCause()!=null?". "+e.getCause():"");
        logger.error(mess);
    }
}
```

But I get FileNotFoundException:

```
com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponseException: 404 Not Found
{
 "error": {"theID"
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "notFound",
    "message": "File not found: 1tvnGWDCse4TFQwIvqEDTlvv2cebfs0C2JBtjTP5A42I.",
    "locationType": "parameter",
    "location": "fileId"
   }
  ],
  "code": 404,
  "message": "File not found: theID."
 }
}
```

Does anyone know why this might be happening?
Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** I have just compared the id received with the one given by Google with the file's link and they are exactly the same.

**EDIT 2:** If I do `driveService.files().list();` it returns an empty list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Tanaike said I had to use export instead of get but also executeAndDownloadTo instead of executeMediaAndDownloadTo

So it worked being:

```
String fileId = "## file ID ##";
OutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
driveService.files().export(fileId, "application/pdf")
    .executeAndDownloadTo(outputStream);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to download Google Docs, please use files.export. Can you reflect the following script and try it?

```
String fileId = "## file ID ##";
OutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
driveService.files().export(fileId, "application/pdf")
    .executeMediaAndDownloadTo(outputStream);
```

- This sample script and the detail information are [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads#downloading_google_documents).

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it gave the same error, 404 File not found

Comment: @Aldeguer I'm sorry  for the inconvenience. I saw your EDIT2, just now. Can I ask you whether the file you want to download is in your Google Drive?

Comment: Yes, it is, I am selecting it from a drive's doc made with Google Picker and JS. I have tried both, one file created by me and other created by a mate but shared with me. No one worked

Comment: @Aldeguer About the empty of ``driveService.files().list();``, what fields did you set for the request? And, as a sample, can you create new Google Document on your Google Drive and try to retrieve file list using your script? If the list includes the created file, your script may be able to download the file.

Comment: Ehm I am not getting your question, I am quite noob in this area, sorry about that. I did: `com.google.api.services.drive.Drive.Files.List list = driveService.files().list();`. I will try your sample and tell you about the result. Thanks for all dude

Comment: @Aldeguer When the file list doesn't include the file you want to download, ``driveService.files().export()`` also cannot retrieve the file information. So I had wanted to confirm about retrieving file list. I'm sorry for my poor English skill.

Comment: I tried creating a file and getting the list and it is still empty. Code: `driveService.files().create(new File().setId("qwerty1234"));
         com.google.api.services.drive.Drive.Files.List list2 = driveService.files().list();`. Might it be because of google credentials?

Comment: @Aldeguer About the google credentials, if you want to simple sample script for retrieving file list, there is a Quickstart. This is Quickstart using ``files().list()``. https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/java If there are some files in your Google Drive, the file list can be retrieved. I have to be away from now. My response becomes late. I'm sorry.